# Usage of light node through the HTTP API

Tags: les

Am I correctly understanding that all I have to do to use a ethereum light node (started with a syncmode=light) is to call regular ethereum api as described in https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC ? So that I just call of those functions with eth_ prefix and I don't have to call the functions like GetBlockHeaders as described in LES specification:https://github.com/zsfelfoldi/go-ethereum/wiki/Light-Ethereum-Subprotocol-%28LES%29 ?
So that geth will do everything w/o my help.  Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LES protocol is the specification for the inter-node communication.

For user interaction, you can simply use the JSON RPC calls or web3 to query the node, however, not everything will be available like with the full node.

> The Light Ethereum Subprotocol (LES) is the protocol used by "light" clients, which only download block headers as they appear and fetch other parts of the blockchain on-demand.